# Преобразовать метод с помощью лямбд

Tags: android, kotlin, eventbus

Есть метод, который хочется сократить (как вариант который нашёл вынести в параметры имя класса и лямбду) но не совсем понятен данный способ:

```
private fun processStickyEvents(Class.name, lambda) {
...
}
```

Вот собственно и сам метод:

```
private fun processStickyEvents() {
    EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(FirstClass::class.java)?.let { onFirstEvent(it)  }
    EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(SecondClass::class.java)?.let { onSecondEvent(it)  }
    EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(AnotherClass::class.java)?.let { onAnotherEvent(it)  }
    EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(FirstClass::class.java)
    EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(SecondClass::class.java)
    EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(AnotherClass::class.java)
}
```

Также на одном из форумов нашёл такое решение, которое к сожалению пока тоже не совсем укладывается в голове:

> currently it looks something like `fun <T: Any> getStickyEvent(type: Class<T>): T?` you can make it reified `inline fun <reified T: Any> getStickyEvent(): T?` then you can use `T::class.java` as your replacement for the `type` argument you used before

Кто может наставить на путь истинный ребята?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае будет выглядеть так

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    processStickyEvents<FirstClass>{ onFirstEvent(it) }
    processStickyEvents<SecondClass>{ onSecondEvent(it) }
    processStickyEvents<AnotherClass>{ onAnotherEvent(it) }
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> processStickyEvents(lambda: (T) -> Unit) {
    EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(T::class.java)?.let { lambda(it)  }
    EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(T::class.java)
}
```

Comment: Тупанул, сейчас поправлю, сам только учусь на нём писать

Comment: Выглядит неплохо, но можно чуть чуть пояснить данное решение?  + по прежнему не совсем понимаю как теперь впихнуть туда мои классы с методами?)

Comment: Добавил конкретики :)

Comment: Вот я тугодум)
ок) что то подобное я пытался сделать, но не уверен что это решение более элегантней начального, как считаете?

Comment: ну как сказать, на мой взгляд лучше, т.к. всё в одном месте, не надо будет менять кучу строк, если что-то изменится + если вызывать эту функцию более 3 раз, то количество строк уже будет меньше, чем изначальным способом

Comment: Соглашусь) и последний вопрос, вызывать данную функцию мне нужно ведь через main? Как правильно передавать параметры `args`?

Comment: нет, main это главная функция, она просто для демонстрации, через неё запускается обычное приложение написанное на Kotlin (не android), вызывать этот метод вы можете там, где вы вызываете `processStickyEvents` сейчас

Comment: Тогда получается вместо `processStickyEvents()` я должен буду вызывать что то подобное `processStickyEvents<> {  }`?

Comment: да, как в примере

Comment: @Inkognito я думаю будет не лишним полистать https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html для большего понимания встроенных функций.

Comment: А вызвать сам метод можете примерно следующим образом `processStickyEvents<Any> { it }`